# more than 1 Customized HTML Audio player UI on one HTML page

Tags: html, audio

I'm trying to create 3 separate instances of a very simple, minimal customized HTML Audio player embedded into the page to play 3 mp3 files.

I have no problem creating one, works and looks like it's supposed to:

```
<div id="w">
 <div id="content">
  <div class="audio-player">
   <h3>Betty'sBastardBopBits</h3>
   <audio id="audio-player" src="BettysBastardBopBits.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
    </div><!-- @end .audio-player -->
   </div><!-- @end #content -->
  </div><!-- @end #w -->
```

and the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#audio-player').mediaelementplayer({
    alwaysShowControls: true,
    features: ['playpause','progress','volume'],
    audioVolume: 'horizontal',
    audioWidth: 600,
    audioHeight: 100,
    iPadUseNativeControls: true,
    iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
    AndroidUseNativeControls: true
  });
 });
</script>
```

For the other 2, i duplicated this code changing in all 3 instances
`<audio id="audio-player"` to `<audio class="audio-player"`
and in the JavaScript
`$('#audio-player')` to `$('.audio-player')`in the html document.

However, nothing shows up now and where the players are supposed to be it only says "Download File".

How can i fix this?

Comment: maybe you could fiddle with this http://jsfiddle.net/xt9wm0f2/

Comment: _italic_ and **bold** ok thanks